# Simple shortening of my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to simplify this code using for loops. Any help is appreciated.

I am setting up a system of opening modal frames full of images when somebody clicks on a link with a date on it (e.g. a photo archive). I have a lot of different dates and each time I make a new one I have to insert it a million times into the code as shown below. Maybe I could make an array of some sort that holds the dates and loop through the array and generate the code below. There is probably a simple fix to this, but I am new to web development. Thanks!!!!

```js
// Get the modal gallery
var gallery161207 = document.getElementById('gallery161207');
var gallery161130 = document.getElementById('gallery161130');
...
var gallery150916 = document.getElementById('gallery150916');

// Get the close button
var closeButton161207 = document.getElementById('closeModal161207');
var closeButton161130 = document.getElementById('closeModal161130');
...
var closeButton150916 = document.getElementById('closeModal150916');

// Get the buttons
var btn161207 = document.getElementById('161207');
var btn161130 = document.getElementById('161130');
...
var btn150916 = document.getElementById('150916');

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal gallery
function openGallery(source) {
 // Open the modal gallery depending on what was clicked
 if (source == '161207')
  gallery161207.style.display = "block";
 if (source == '161130')
  gallery161130.style.display = "block";
 ...
 if (source == '150916')
  gallery150916.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
closeButton161207.onclick = function() {
    gallery161207.style.display = "none";
}
closeButton161130.onclick = function() {
    gallery161130.style.display = "none";
}
...
closeButton150916.onclick = function() {
    gallery150916.style.display = "none";
}

btn161207.onclick = function() { openGallery('161207'); }
btn161130.onclick = function() { openGallery('161130'); }
...
btn150916.onclick = function() { openGallery('150916'); }

window.onclick = function(event) {
 if (event.target == gallery161207) {
  closeButton161207.onclick();
 }
 if (event.target == gallery161130) {
  closeButton161130.onclick();
 }
 ...
 if (event.target == gallery150916) {
  closeButton150916.onclick();
 }
}
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I truly love you for that comment.

Comment: Thanks! Although some things about the languages are also extremely similar such as syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making an object saving all the dom references and using those. This answer makes use of jQuery for its document ready function.

```js
var sourceList = [];
var sources = {};
var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-wrapper');
for(var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++){
    sourceList.push(wrappers[i].id);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < sourceList.length; i++){
        var source = {};
        source.gallery = document.getElementById("gallery"+sourceList[i]); 
        source.button = document.getElementById("button"+sourceList[i]);
        source.closeButton = document.getElementById('closeButton'+sourceList[i]);
        source.button.onclick = function() {
            if(source.gallery)source.gallery.style.display = "block";
        }
        source.closeButton.onclick = function() {
            if(source.gallery)source.gallery.style.display = "none";
        }
        sources[sourceList[i]] = source;
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        for (var source in sources) 
            if (event.target == sources[source].gallery) 
                sources[source].closeButton.onclick();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this fairly easily using jQuery, but I assume, since you're new to web development, you'll want to start out from scratch.

First, let's deal with setting up the buttons to show the galleries. I'd say you give each button a `class="gallery-button"` attribute and an `id="<id of gallery>"`. The galleries also should have IDs `id="gallery-<id of gallery>"`. Then:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-button"); 
for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++){ 
  var elem = buttons[i];
  elem.onclick = function() { 
    document.getElementById('gallery' + elem.id).style.display="block";
    };
  }
}
```

We can do a similar thing for the close buttons (assuming they have IDs of `id="close-<id of gallery>"` and their `class="close-button"`:

```
var closeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button"); 
for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++){ 
  var elem = closeButtons[i];
  elem.onclick = function() { 
    document.getElementById('gallery-' + elem.id.replace("close-", "")).style.display="none";
    };
  }
}
```

And then:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var id = event.target.id;
  if (id.startsWith("gallery-") {
    var closeButton = document.getElementById("close-" + id.replace("gallery-", ""));
    closeButton.onclick(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I figured that out on my own but that's along the lines of what I did. :)